# What does the three-parameters version of BeginInvoke do?

Tags: c#, begininvoke

I've been reading some code about Data Virtualization on the internet. I met with a function called BeginInvoke. Basically, I know what it is used for. But this function has a version with three parameters which I didn't look up in MSDN.

I did find it in MSDN which has two parameters at most:

[Control.BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also I don't think this is the one I want:

[Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx)

Because the three-parameters version has a DispatcherPriority type for its first parameter which the code I read doesn't pass.

**The code I'm reading is:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace WPF.DataVirtualization
{
    public class AsyncDataRef<TId, T> : DataRefBase<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly TId m_Id;
        private int m_Loading;
        private readonly Func<TId, T> Load;
        private volatile T m_Data;

        public AsyncDataRef(TId id, Func<TId, T> load)
        {
            m_Id = id;
            Load = load;
        }

        public override T Data
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_Data != null)
                    return m_Data;
                if (Interlocked.Increment(ref m_Loading) == 1)
                    if (m_Data == null)
                        Load.BeginInvoke(m_Id, AsyncLoadCallback, null);
                    else
                        Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_Loading);
                else
                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_Loading);
                return m_Data;
            }
        }


        private void AsyncLoadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            m_Data = Load.EndInvoke(ar);
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_Loading);
            // when the object is loaded, signal that all the properties have changed
            NotifyAllPropertiesChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**And when call this function, it uses it like this:**

```
var list = new List<DataRefBase<Person>>(itemCount);
...
list.Add(new AsyncDataRef<int, Person>(i, LoadPerson));
```

Person is another kind of class. LoadPerson is a delegate function. DataRefBase is a kind of template class.

**My question is this line:**

```
Load.BeginInvoke(m_Id, AsyncLoadCallback, null);
```

What do the three parameters do? (It seems that m_Id is used as an int)What do they stand for? Where can I find the document of this version of BeginInvoke.

Comment: As i think (it's just a suggestion), this parameter is a parameter, which will be passed to callback on it's ivocation

Comment: "I did find it in MSDN" - no you didn't; you found two other unrelated methods with the same name. Just because it has the same name doesn't mean it has the same meaning; `Delegate.BeginInvoke` is very different to `Control.BeginInvoke`, for example. What does the intellisense or documentation say about DataVirtualization's `BeginInvoke`? Heck, *what is the parameter called*?

Comment: A somewhat similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961450/where-are-clr-defined-methods-like-delegate-begininvoke-documented

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Beginning an Asynchronous Operation**
>
> A **Begin***OperationName* method takes any parameters declared in the signature of
> the synchronous version of the method that are passed by value or by reference. Any out parameters are not part of the **Begin**_OperationName_method signature. The **Begin**_OperationName_method signature also includes two additional parameters. The first of these defines an AsyncCallback delegate that references a method that is called when the asynchronous operation completes. The caller can specify null (Nothing in Visual Basic) if it does not want a method invoked when the operation completes. The second additional parameter is a user-defined object. This object can be used to pass application-specific state information to the method invoked when the asynchronous operation completes.

Since Load is a `Func<TId, T>`, it's `BeginInvoke` method has three parameters with the following types:

- `TId` (passed to the method/delegate that is called asynchronously)
- [`AsyncCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (called when the asynchronous operation completes)
- `object` (used to pass around a state).

Comment: `TId` is passed to `AsyncCallback`? But `AsyncCallback` only has one parameter which is `IAsyncResult` type. And when the code use it, pass an int to it. So how could it be the parameter passed to the delegate method?

Comment: No, the `TId` is not passed to he AsyncCallback. It's passed to `Load`. `Load` is a `Func<TId, T>`, so it expects a `TId` as first parameter. You call `Load(somethingThatIsTid)` synchronously and `Load.BeginInvoke(somethingThatIsTid, somethingThatIsCalledWhenLoadFinished, something)` asynchronously.

Comment: The third parameter, the object, according to the document, "This object can be used to pass application-specific state information to the method invoked when the asynchronous operation completes." I wonder, how does it pass to the delegate method. By passing parameters or what?