# Why do I not see the presence of BeginInvoke and EndInvoke methods in Delegate class?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I can see BeginInvoke and EndInvoke methods are available for any delegate. But I don't see them defined anywhere in "Delegate" and "MulticastDelegate" classes. Where are they present?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/q/14961450/4430204](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14961450/4430204)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are CLR-defined methods like \[delegate\].BeginInvoke documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961450/where-are-clr-defined-methods-like-delegate-begininvoke-documented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The common language runtime provides each delegate type with BeginInvoke and EndInvoke methods, to enable asynchronous invocation of the delegate. For more information about these methods, see [Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/calling-synchronous-methods-asynchronously).